# Express cannot GET using POST http request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

**EDIT: Also my goal is to add the new `user` to my `accounts` arrray. Thanks**
I'm new to express and I'm trying to learn it. Currently I am trying to learn basic http requests. I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-express-routing), so far so good until I get to the POST request and I get error: `Cannot GET /accounts/add-account`, I've tried what I know and what I can find with my limited googling skills and I'm stuck.

here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Express server currently running on port ${PORT}`));

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json("Hello");
});

//define http methods
let accounts = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "fakeemail@emai.com",
    "password": "qw1212",
}];

//list all accounts
app.get('/accounts', (request, response) => {
    response.json(accounts);
});

//get account by id
app.get('/accounts/accountid/:id', (request, response) => {
    const accountId = Number(request.params.id);
    const getAccount = accounts.find((account) => account.id === accountId);

    if (!getAccount) {
        response.status(500).send('Account not found.')
    } else {
        response.json(getAccount);
    }
});

app.post('/accounts/add-account', (request, response) => {
    const newAccount = {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Dohn Joe",
        "email": "realemail@emai.com",
        "password": "abc123",
    };
    accounts.push(newAccount);
    response.json(accounts);
})
```

Thanks

Comment: You get this error because this is __not__ a POST request. Notice the `Cannot >>>GET<<< /accounts/add-account`

Comment: @tkausl Actually is a `post` route

Comment: Send a POST request and it'll work. The HTTP verb should match the method.

Comment: @ask4you But not a POST _Request_.

Comment: @tkausl That's true. Just change from get to post method.

Comment: Please show the client-side of things so we can see why it isn't a POST, but is a GET instead.

Comment: I am using `app.post()` method for creating account, is still not correct? Thanks

Comment: also this is my url `http://localhost:3000/accounts/add-account` when getting this error. thanks

Comment: from where you are fetching the url? looks like from the browser, but be aware that the browser only supports get requests and not post, so in order to make any request other then get you will need to have an application something like postman

Comment: Typing a URL into the browser bar ONLY does a GET request.  To issue a POST from the browser, you have to either configure a `<form>` properly to use a POST upon form submission or you have to use a `fetch()` (or similar) call from Javascript in the web page that is configured to make a POST request.  Typing into the URL bar ALWAYS issues a GET request, never a POST request.